# Update column based on multiple table inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few tables as shown below, where `OrigMachine.ID` and `OrigKeys.Id` are same.

`OrigMachine: ID, Name`
`OrigKeys :ID, Key`

`BackupMachine : ID,Name`
`BackupKeys : ID, Key`

For example, My `OrigMachine` table is as shown below.

```
ID, Name
1,  Alfa
2,  Beta
```

My `BackupMachine` table is as shown below.

```
ID, Name
1,  Beta
2,  Gamma
```

My `OrigKeys` table is as shown below.

```
ID, Name
1,  AlfaParticle
2,  Beta1particle
```

My `backupKeys` table is as shown below.

```
ID, Name
1,  BetaParticle
2,  GammaParticle
```

After the update, the expected `OrigKeys` table is as shown below.

```
ID, Name
1,  AlfaParticle
2,  BetaParticle
```

Need to update OrigKeys.Key with BackupKeys.Key, based on OrigMachine.Name = BackupMachine.Name

This is what i have came up with, but not seems to work.

```
UPDATE [DB].[dbo].[OrigKeys]
SET [DB].[dbo].[OrigKeys].[Key] = [TS2].[Key]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[BackupMachine] AS TM2
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[BackupKeys] TS2 ON [TS2].[Id] = [TM2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[OrigMachine] TM1 ON [TM1].[Name] = [TM2].[Name]
WHERE [TM1].[Name] = [TM2].[Name];
```

What am i missing?

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question which explains what you are trying to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Org  
SET Org.[Key] = TS2.[Key]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[BackupMachine] AS TM2
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[BackupKeys] TS2 ON [TS2].[Id] = [TM2].[Id]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[OrigMachine] TM1 ON [TM1].[Name] = [TM2].[Name]
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[OrigKeys] AS Org ON Org.ID = TM1.ID;
```

Comment: There is no TM2.[Key], meant to say TS2.key?

Comment: so you are saying there is no `key` exists in your `backupkeys` table?

Comment: Updated the question with sample data. btw, there is no relationship b/w the ID's of original and backup tables. i.e, origmachine.id != bakmachine.id.

Comment: we are not mapping anywhere ID's of original and backup tables. i.e, origmachine.id != bakmachine.id. We are mapping them on the basis of name's of original and backup tables. i.e, origmachine.name = bakmachine.name. I think atleast that relation is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - you need to specify the alias name in the time of update as you've defined the alias for your table name

```
UPDATE TM1 
SET TM1.[Key] = TS2.[Key]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[BackupMachine] AS TM2
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[BackupKeys] TS2 ON TS2.[Id] = TM2.[Id]
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[OrigMachine] TM1 ON TM1.[Name] = TM2.[Name]
```

Comment: There is no TM1.[Key], meant to say TS1.Key?